# Buttons not aligning to the bottom of overlaid showcase boxes CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

The buttons in my **showcase boxes** aren't aligning to the bottom of each of their respective showcase-box. They change position with the different amount of text in there. I have tried so many things and lots of searching. I tried (position: absolute; margin-bottom: 5px;) but they jumped right out of the boxes they are in.

Expected outcome is the button is at the bottom of the showcase-box (say 5px up, but aligned centrally within the showcase-box)

I have a showcase which is the black background, then the 3 showcase-boxes. Each box has a h3, para and the button.

Here's the link to my bin: https://jsbin.com/hacatebaqe/1/edit?html,css,output

HTML is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="showcase">
    <div class="showcase-box">
        <h3><a href="getstarted.html">Where do i start?</a></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed.                   
        </p>
        <button class="showcase-button">Start Here...</button>
    </div>
<div class="showcase-box">
    <h3><a href="#">Ready for more?</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
    </p>
    <button class="showcase-button">Learn More...</button>
  </div>

<div class="showcase-box">
    <h3><a href="#">Where to next?</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <button class="showcase-button">Next steps...</button>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS is:

```
.showcase {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #4784B0;

    text-align: center;
}

.showcase-box {
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    min-height: 250px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    display: inline-table;
    width: 30%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 10px 18px 18px  #004372;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center
}

.showcase-box h3 a {

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
    /*color: black;*/

}

.showcase-box p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: .9em;
    color: black;
}


.showcase-button {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    border: none;
    background-color: #616161;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 100px;
    box-shadow:  2px 2px 3px black ;

}

    .showcase-button:hover {
        background-color: #fb4833;
        color: white;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added position `relative` to the `.showcase-box` then create a `div`, set it to position `absolute`, center and position the element inside it, to contain the button (button is an inline element and may have problems positioning even when set to position absolute in a div)

```css
.showcase {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #4784B0;
    text-align: center;
}

.showcase-box {
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    min-height: 250px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    display: inline-table;
    width: 30%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 10px 18px 18px  #004372;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
   position: relative;
}

.showcase-box h3 a {    
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
    /*color: black;*/      
}

.showcase-box p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: .9em;
    color: black;

}

.showcase-button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 15px; 
}
.showcase-button > button{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    border: none;
    background-color: #616161;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 100px;
    box-shadow:  2px 2px 3px black ;
}

.showcase-button >button:hover {
    background-color: #fb4833;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
    <div class="showcase-box">
        <h3><a href="getstarted.html">Where do i start?</a></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed.                   
        </p>
        <div class="showcase-button">
      <button>Start Here...</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="showcase-box">
    <h3><a href="#">Ready for more?</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
    </p>
    <div class="showcase-button">
      <button>Learn More...</button>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="showcase-box">
    <h3><a href="#">Where to next?</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <div class="showcase-button"><button>Next steps...</button></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) @K.C.